# Linear regression - object not found when using predict

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have found that there are similar questions to mine on this forum, but I haven't been able to use them to solve my problem. I have been able to build a regression model using two variables, which works fine. However, when I try to use the predict function I get an error.

This code works:

```
model<-lm(Revenue~x,data=comb_data)

summary(model)

predict(model, data.frame(x=75000), interval = 'confidence')
```

However the below, the initial regression model works but the predict function does not. I get this error

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found.

This is despite 'y' being in the data frame I used previously

```
model<-lm(Revenue~x+y,data=comb_data)

summary(model)

predict(model, data.frame(x=75000, y=50), interval = 'confidence')
```

Comment: You have a mix of `Y` and `y` in your post. R is case sensitive. Please check what is in the data set `comb_data`, in the model formula and in the new data.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when I was copying and pasting in. All of the variables are 'y'

Comment: Hi awz1. Welcome to SO! Please provide some information about the structure of `comb_data`. I suggest, there is no `y` in `comb_data`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(comb_data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(comb_data, 20))`.